# How to permanently change TTL on macOS Catalina?

Tags: network, catalina

Before macOS Catalina it was possible to permanently change TTL by creating /etc/sysctl.conf file. It seems this is not an option anymore. After Catalina upgrade the file was moved to my desktop with the message that it is no longer compatible with macOS security settings.

What would be the best way to do it now in macOS Catalina?

Comment: [How do you change the TTL in macOS High Sierra?](https://superuser.com/a/1516451/374285). As stated in this answer it works for Catalina.

Answer (score 3):

The classic method with `/etc/sysctl.conf` still works for macOS Catalina, but only after disabling [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) since El Capitan.